# check if part of my dict/struct is in list [python]

Tags: python

My list is like below:

```
list = [{'a', 'b', 1}, {'x', 'y', 2}]
```

I have my variables and I only want to match the first 2 letters.

```
aa = {'x', 'y', 2}
bb = {'x', 'z', 2}
```

So, `aa` in `list` is `True` but `bb` in `list` is `False`.

I've tried to use `{'x', 'y', _}` in `list`. But this sometimes return `True` and sometimes `False`? This might because the letters are not in order, because when I print `list`, I see the letters are actually in random order? Any help please?

Comment: `{'a', 'b', 2}` is a `set` instance, and sets are unordered. You probably want to be using lists (`['a', 'b', 2]`) or tuples (`('a', 'b', 2)`). Also, it's a very bad idea to use `list` as a variable name, since that masks the name of the builtin `list` type.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you mean to be working on lists or tuples, not sets, so you can use an `itemgetter` here:

```
from operator import itemgetter

first_two = itemgetter(0, 1)

l = [['a', 'b', 1], ['x', 'y', 2]]    # list of lists
aa = ['x', 'y', 2]
bb = ['x', 'z', 2]
cc = ('a', 'b', 100)

>>> first_two(aa) in (first_two(x) for x in l)
True
>>> first_two(bb) in (first_two(x) for x in l)
False
>>> first_two(cc) in (first_two(x) for x in l)
True
```

`first_two` is an `itemgetter` that will return a tuple containing the corresponding elements from the given sequence. This is applied to each item in the list `l` with a generator expression, extracting the first two elements of each item in the list. Similarly the first two elements of each variable (`aa`, `bb`, etc) are extracted. The resulting tuples are then compared to get a boolean result.

You could generalise this into a function:

```
def part_in(value, sequence, getter=None):
    if getter is None:
        getter = itemgetter(*range(len(value)))    # compare on all items
    return getter(value) in (getter(x) for x in sequence if len(x) >= len(value))

>>> part_in(aa, l)
True
>>> part_in(aa, l, itemgetter(0, 1))
True
>>> part_in(aa, l, itemgetter(0, 2))    # considers first and third items only
True
```

The last example shows that it's easy to select and compare any set of indices for the items.

Answer (score 0):

Using a function:

```
def compare_sequences(main_sequence=None, compared_sequence=None, elements=2):
    for seq in main_sequence:
        if compared_sequence[:elements] == seq[:elements]:
            return True 
    return False

my_tuples = (('a', 'b', 1), ('x', 'y', 2))
aa = ('x', 'y', 2)
bb = ('x', 'z', 2)
print(compare_sequences(my_tuples, aa, 2))
```

> > True